# Alternating colors in DataGridView For windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I set alternating colors in DataGridView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the alternating row style is the easiest. If you need more control, you can set it using the row binding event with a custom algorithm. I don't think you need to do that, however. If you want something complex, I would suggest buying a third party control library, as they handle the complex scenarios without a lot of coding.

Just saw you were doing win forms. Still pretty much the same thing. Set the alternating row. And, there are more complex grids out there you can purchase. So the answer still holds for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Using a theme for the gridview ;) 
[Read it here:MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)

EXAMPLE:

a skin file example:

`<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
<RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount = "5" />
</asp:GridView>`

CSS:
'
    .AlternatingRowStyle
{
    background-color: #A9D0F5;
}

.RowStyle
{
    background-color: #E0E0F8;
}

.SelectedRowStyle
{
    background-color: #2E2EFE;
}

'

Comment: He is not doing ASP.NET. Just discovered that by looking at his other posts.

Comment: Shame, just looked up an example for him :p